# Memory leak in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have bisected my code and determined that this causes a memory leak. Can somebody explain why?

`self.overlay` is an `UIImageView`, set in IB. The property is declared as `(nonatomic, weak)`.

If I comment out this while block I don't get the malloc error. If I only comment out the // Graphics operations here (as shown below) I still get the malloc error.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.overlay.frame.size, NO, 0);

// Graphics operations here

self.overlay.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: These lines alone shouldn't be a leak since you end the context on the last line. What is the static analyzer telling you? Maybe you are leaking some colorRef or somethings like that...

Comment: Well, you'd think so, but no dice. Here's the thing: If I comment out the entire method, no memory error. If I leave just those three lines active, and everything else commented: Memory error. Static analyzer has no problem with any of it.

Comment: Is it Instruments that is telling you that its a leak then? What kind of data does it say gets leaked?

Comment: Nope, it's a symbolic breakpoint on malloc_error_break, but its location seems to move around. All I know at the moment is that it goes away if I uncomment the image context code above. I don't have much experience with Instruments, and don't know how to pinpoint the cause.